# awk - calculations across lines of an ascii-file

Tags: awk

I have an ascii-file with the following structure:

```
1,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
1,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
1,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
1,0,3,0,0,0,0.04,0,0,990,0
1,0,3,0,0,0,0.12,0,0,3760,0
1,0,3,0,0,0,0.21,0,0,5372,0
1,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
1,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
1,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
1,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
1,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
1,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
.
.
.
```

The zeros stand for "random" numbers I need not to take care of.

Where column 3 is equal to 3 (always a block of three) I have
to perform some calculations with the columns 7 and 10:

I need to calculate (0.04*990)+(0.12*3760)+(0.21*5372) 
and insert the result in column 5 of all three lines.
The values in column 10 will be different in the next "block of three".

Previously I have done a lot ascii-file editing with awk, so if possible I would like to use it here also.

My main problem is to access the next two lines after finding column 3 = 3 and then to continue searching two lines further.

---

The result should look like this:

```
1,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
1,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
1,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
1,0,3,0,1618.92,0,0.04,0,0,990,0
1,0,3,0,1618.92,0,0.12,0,0,3760,0
1,0,3,0,1618.92,0,0.21,0,0,5372,0
1,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
1,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
1,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
1,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
1,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
1,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
.
.
.
```

I hope that I was able to describe the problem, if not just ask and I will clarify!

---

I tried:

```
awk -F"," '$3 == "3"' in.dat > out.dat
```

and to combine it with

```
awk -v "n=line numer" -v "s=string to insert" '(NR==n) { print s } 1' input-file
```

but my main problem is that I did not know how to access the fields after the first line and to use it in a formula for calculation.

The formula I really need to use is way more complex, but I only posted here a simple example because it is no problem to adapt it to a more complex solution.

Comment: so what did you do so far? where are you stuck? Also, as it is a fixed value, why don't you just add it as it is instead of doing the calculation every single time?

Comment: I tried: awk -F"," '$3 == "3"' in.dat > out.dat and to combine it with   awk -v "n=line numer" -v "s=string to insert" '(NR==n) { print s } 1' input-file but my main problem is that I did not know how to access the fields after the first line and to use it in a formula for calculation.

Comment: The formula I really need to use is way more complex, but I only posted here a simple example because it is no problem to adapt it to a more complex solution

Comment: ... and the values in column 10 are different in the next "block" of three (I forgot to mention, sorry)

Comment: It is very good that you provide such informations, they make the problem more clear. However, here in comments are not noticed by people, so you'd better edit your question and add these details. Also, give feedback to the people that already answered. Finally, you can take a look to this page: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thanks for your fast feedback! I updated my question!

Comment: You have to comment in the answers, not posting another one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

awk's `getline` command serves you well here

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '
    $3 == 3 {
        c = 0
        line1 = $0; c += $7 * $10; getline
        line2 = $0; c += $7 * $10; getline
        line3 = $0; c += $7 * $10
        $0 = line1; $5 = c; print
        $0 = line2; $5 = c; print
        $0 = line3; $5 = c
    }
    {print}
'
```

That's not DRY enough for my tastes, but it's only 3 lines and pretty readable.

DRY Solution

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '
    $3 == 3 {
        c = 0
        for(i=1;i<=3;i++)
        {line[i] = $0; c += $7 * $10; getline}
        for(i=1;i<=3;i++)
        {$0 = line[i]; $5 = c; print}
        next
    }1
'
```

Comment: very readable, and I think's the data that's not DRY, you can only do so much! ;-)

Comment: @glennjackman, i added an edit for a dryer solution, it was too long to add in a comment and also i didn't want to plagiarise in my own answer, feel free to delete it if you want though :)

Answer (score 2):

In awk

```
awk -F, '$3=="3"{a[++x]=$0;y+=($7*$10)}
         !x
         x==3{
            while(++i<=x){
                    split(a[i],b,",")
                    b[5]=y
                    for(j=1;j<length(b);j++)
                            c=j>1?c","b[j]:b[j]
                            print c
                            c=t
            }
            x=y=i=0
    }' file
```

- If 3 is third field then Save line into array `a` and add the total to variable `y`
- print if x is 0
- If x is 3(i.e the third line)for the three lines in the array split them into another array
- Change 5th element to y(total).
- Recreate line in another loop.
- Print line.

Shorter,less resource hungry way(credit to glenn jackmans answer for giving me the idea)

```
awk -F, '$3=="3"{a[++x]=$0;y+=($7*$10)}
         !x
         x==3{
            while(++i<=x){
                    $0=a[i]
                    $5=y
                    print
            }
            i=y=x=0
    }' test
```

Comment: I also liked your solution, but I will go with glenn jackman's because it is easier to adapt to my (more complex) formula.